# Error "step is not defind" using Mocha Test and what is mean by "Then simply run mocha with --require mocha-steps" in tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, karma-mocha

> `describe('my smoke test', function() {

step('login', function() {

```
vdriver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('UserName'))).sendKeys("aqdjska@gmail.org");
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("mat-input-3"))).sendKeys("cool123");
driver.sleep(2000);
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".mat-progress-spinner-light > div"))).click();
```

});

step('Open Apps', function() {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Apps')]"))).click();
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".app-item:nth-child(7) .icon-prepend"))).click();
  });

step('Create A Theme', function() {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Themes')]"))).click();

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/os-commerce/os-commerce-root/div[2]/div/app-builder/pe-builder-themes-list/div[2]/pe-builder-themes-list-user/div/pe-builder-theme-plus/mat-card/mat-card-content"))).click();

driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/os-commerce/os-commerce-root/div[2]/div/app-builder/pe-builder-theme/pe-editor/div[1]/pe-builder-navbar-top/mat-toolbar/mat-toolbar-row/pe-builder-navbar-top-button[4]/button/span"))).click();
```

});

xstep('temporarily ignored', function() {
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Close')]"))).click();
  });

});
`

above is the code

Comment: Please don't post your question twice.

Comment: Sorry it was uploaded twice by mistake